# C++ 11 Regex Iterator Overload Compiler Error

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

I'm a bit new to regular expressions in C++. My head is spinning a bit because its turning out to be a lot more complex than I'd imagined.

In my actual code (which I abbreviated below) I want to use an iterator to move from place to place in a large string pulling out different pieces of information. Right now I'm having trouble even getting this code to compile.

```
string email1S = "abc 31432";
smatch results;
regex mcn("([[:digit:]]+)");
string::const_iterator curPosition = email1S.begin();

if (regex_search(curPosition, email1S.end(), results, mcn))
{
    cout << "We have a match" << endl;
    cout << results[1].str() << endl;
}
curPosition += results[0].length();
```

The line:

```
if (regex_search(curPosition, email1S.end(), results, mcn))
```

Is apparently not matching any overloads for regex_search. The error (from Visual Studio 2010) is describes it as if its looking to use an entirely different overload:

```
Error   1   error C2780: 'bool std::tr1::regex_search(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &,const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided
```

I must be missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

The types of first and second parameters must be the same(if these parameters are iterators). You can use, for example, function `cend()` instead of `end()`:

```
if (regex_search(curPosition, email1S.cend(), results, mcn))
```

Comment: I gave that a shot but its still not compiling. I think this is the error that associates with the overload I'm trying to get:
`Error 8 error C2782: 'bool std::tr1::regex_search(_BidIt,_BidIt,std::tr1::match_results<_BidIt,_Alloc> &,const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : template parameter '_BidIt' is ambiguous`
**Edit:** Put the right error in.

Comment: @FrankWeindel, can you post the list of ambiguities, please? This code compiles with both clang and g++ without any errors.

Comment: @FrankWeindel - when you "gave that a shot", presumably you wrote some code. Post that code.

Comment: I simply did what @soon had suggested. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/NnTAhLFC

Comment: I see what I did. When I did what @soon suggested, I forgot I had changed "smatch" to "cmatch" in a prior attempt to figure this out. That caused confusion to the compiler about which type it was supposed to generate for. I wish these error messages were somewhat clearer though.